# Is power through a surface Lorentz invariant?

Tags: electromagnetism, special-relativity, power, poynting-vector

I am trying to solve this problem from Griffiths, but my point is not really to ask the answer of this problem :

> A point charge $q$ is moving velocity $v$ parallel to $x$ axis. determine the total power passing through the plane at $x = a$ when charge is at origin.

Now, I know how to find the fields in the frame for which charge is moving as stated, but for conceptual understanding I am interested in the following question:

> Is energy delivered by EM field observer independent? In this case through the plane?

Intuitively, energy seems like a scalar, so I can guess that it would, but then if in the frame of problem there is power (there is), in the frame moving with the charge, there is no power delivered. Does this mean power through surface is not a scalar (the way it transforms)?

Note: When I compare power through surfaces in two frames, the second surface is the image of the initial surface after Lorentz boost.

Comment: *energy seems like a scalar* It’s not a Lorentz scalar; it’s the temporal component of the energy-momentum four-vector. (And it’s not a Galilean scalar either.)

Comment: You have answered your own question. Clearly power cannot be invariant. If you move to the rest frame of the charge then there is no magnetic field and no power going anywhere.

Comment: It seems @Ghoster 's answer relies on $p^{\mu}$ for EM field. Idk if this is (if true) well known

Answer (score 0):

It’s frame dependent. The energy density is a function of the fields. The fields are a function of the potentials. The potentials change (via LT) when you switch reference frames (you have to put them in a 4-vector). The energy-impulse vector transforms via LT as well. The vector elements get squished or stretched in a way that preserves the metric.